# How to pivot Feature Value Based On Features Exist on table Input Data?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I work on SQL Server 2012. I have an issue: I can't pivot features for every part existing in the table input data.

I need to display features as pivot where Part C AND Part x exist in the table input data .

I need to show Part C AND Part X AND feature for Part C AND feature For Part X in one row horizontally .

When pivot feature value for every feature I depend on table parts data that have feature name

And feature value for parts that exist in the table input data.

Part data table represent transaction table that I will pivot data from it .

I use display order to arrange features when display based on table features arrange .

I pivot data for every feature based on Part C and Part X exist in the table input data (search table)

```
CREATE TABLE #InputData
(
    PartC INT,
    PartX  int
)

INSERT INTO #InputData (PartC, PartX)
VALUES (1290, 1590)

CREATE TABLE #features
(
    FeatureId  int,
    FeatureName nvarchar(50),
    DisplayOrder  int
)

INSERT INTO #features (FeatureId, FeatureName, DisplayOrder)
VALUES (124003, 'Current', 1),
       (157301, 'Voltage', 2),
       (980012, 'Resistor', 3)

CREATE TABLE #partsdata
(
    PartId  int,
    FeatureId int,
    FeatureValue nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO #partsdata (PartId, FeatureId, FeatureValue)
VALUES (1290, 124003, '40V'),
       (1290, 157301, '50k'),
       (1290, 980012, '90A'),
       (1590, 124003, '30V'),
       (1590, 157301, '70k'),
       (1590, 980012, '20A')
```

Result :

```
 Partc Partx  Current-C Current-X Volt-C Volt-X Resistor-C Resistor-X   
 1290  1590     40V        30V      50k   70k       90A      20A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation like so:

```
select d.partc, d.partx,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partc and f.featurename = 'Current' then featurevalue end) as current_c,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partx and f.featurename = 'Current' then featurevalue end) as current_x,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partc and f.featurename = 'Voltage' then featurevalue end) as voltage_c,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partx and f.featurename = 'Voltage' then featurevalue end) as voltage_x,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partc and f.featurename = 'Resistor' then featurevalue end) as resistor_c,
    max(case when p.partid = d.partx and f.featurename = 'Resistor' then featurevalue end) as resistor_x        
from #partsdata p
inner join #features f on f.featureid = p.featureid
inner join #inputdata d on p.partid in (d.partc, d.partx)
group by d.partc, d.partx
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6edc8c7fc1c17f506d8aaf51f8142bc7)**:

```
partc | partx | current_c | current_x | voltage_c | voltage_x | resistor_c | resistor_x
----: | ----: | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------- | :---------
 1290 |  1590 | 40V       | 30V       | 50k       | 70k       | 90A        | 20A
```